# Free group on two generators and commutators. Why it's enough to add the relation ab=ba?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

I've looked through lots of question on this topics, but I cannot find what I want to prove:

I've seen in a lots of exercises sheets that the abelianization of a free group with two generators (let's call it $G$) is in fact the group given with the presentation $\langle a,b | ab=ba \rangle$. In fact I added the relationship $ab=ba$ forcing commutativity. Intuitively it seems clear to me.

So I tried proving it, let's call $N$ the smallest normal set containing $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, $G/N$ is by definition $\langle a,b | ab=ba \rangle$

With the rule $ab=ba$ I can move all the powers of $a$ in a word to the left and all the power of $b$ to the right. So the quotient is abelian, and so we have $[G,G] \subseteq N$. For the other inclusion, we can argue in this way: $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in [G,G]$ by definition, and so $N \subseteq [G,G]$.

Is it correct?

Then to prove the isomorphism between $G/N$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ I would argue as this:

Consider $\phi \colon G \to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ defined in this way $\phi(a)=(1,0)$ and $\phi(b)=(0,1)$, and extend by linearity. Thanks to the fact that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, the map sum the coefficients of $a$ and the sum of the coefficient of $b$. Clearly it's surjective, and the kernel of such map is precisely the words that are killed if we pass to the quotient $G/N$ (because we would be allowed to move and simplify every power of $a$ and $b$. So the induced maps is injective and surjective and a morphism so we are done.

Is it correct again?

Sorry for posting elementary question, these are my first step with these arguments, so I want to be sure I'm doing it properly

Comment: "Extend by linearity" within this context can be rather confusing to say the least (if not completely wrong). Perhaps "extend by (normal, say) expression of elements in the free group" could be more accurate, though cumbersome. I'd rather go "extend by logic within this context"...

Answer (score 3):

First proof is correct and pretty "efficient". Second proof is correct in idea, but notions that were used not really correct.

1. "Consider $\phi:G→ℤ×ℤ$ defined in this way $\phi(a)=(1,0)$ and $\phi(b)=(0,1)$, and extend by linearity". Word linearity in abstract group is not correct, usually it is used in linear spaces. So in fact you can uniquely extend any map of generators **by definition** of the Free Group.
2. Secondly if you are considering some mapping $\phi:G→ℤ×ℤ$ and it is surjective then by theorem on homomorphisms $G/Ker(\phi) \simeq ℤ×ℤ$. So you have to find $Ker(\phi)$. After that make sure that $Ker(\phi) = [G, G]$ (in this problem) and the second item will be proved.

Comment: Have you got some hints about how to prove that $\text{Ker}(\phi) \subset [G,G]$? because I'm having an hard time proving it

Comment: Assume element $a^{i_1}b^{j_1}\dots a^{i_n}b^{j_n} = x \in Ker(\phi)$ then ($e$ is identity element) $e = \phi(x) = \phi(a)^{i_1}\phi(b)^{j_1}\dots \phi(a)^{i_n}\phi(b)^{j_n}  = \phi(a)^{\sum i_k} \phi(b)^{\sum j_k}$, hence $\sum i_k = \sum j_k = 0$. Try to prove by yourself that such elements are in the $[G, G]$.

Comment: Is it enough to say that such elements would be killed passing to the quotient of the abelianization? and so they must be contained in the commutator?

Comment: If after factorization by $[G,G]$ they will be killed then initially they were in $[G, G]$.